# How to use Content-Security-Policy with localhost files

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I am getting the following error on my page:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

**HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
 </head>
 <body>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

I have tried to use a completely open just to get it working and then work backwards, however I even get the same error with this.

To be clear, this isn't for producition code, this is just to enable my live-reload-webpack on a domain that is using https.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `localhost:`, though I believe using `'self'` (including the single quotes) would also suffice in this situation. There are some odd cases where `*` is not actually all-inclusive (`blob:` for example is also excluded from `*` I believe).

As always it's good to check out your CSP with Google's [Evaluator first](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/).